# Invalid Character in Identifier while fetching data from SFMC

Tags: python

While trying to fetch data using API, I am using the below code:

```
import json
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


​authurl = ''
```

I am getting
**Invalid Character in Identifier**
Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: What identifier is the message pointing at?

Comment: @BoarGules authurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.9 gives a more explicit error message: `SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+200B`. That made it slightly easier to pinpoint the problem. Which is...

There is a character to the left of the identifier `authurl` that cannot be displayed because it is a Unicode zero-width space. I don't know how you managed to get that into your code. I suspect it might have come from cutting and pasting from a web page. The easiest solution is to delete the line, and to be sure, the ones above and below it, and retype it.